# How can i call a function when the user touch Pop Back (Back Button on Bottom Navigation) (Right Bottom button on the phone)

Tags: kotlin

I want to call a function when the user touches Back on the Bottom Navigation? Is there any method or a way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Old

You can override `onBackPressed` method in your activity class.

## Recent (API >= 33)

But `onBackPressed` is deprecated after API 33.
Now you can add callback on `onBackPressedDispatcher` instead to override `onBackPressed`

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // something you want to do
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // ...

        this.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, callback)
    }
```

This code is for `Activity`. If you want to set back button action in Fragment, you can check this document.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher

Answer (score 0):

Use `override fun onBackPressed()` method

```
override fun onBackPressed(){
    // Do something
    // add super.onBackPressed() if you want to call the normal back function
}
```

May this solution help you. 
Thank you